# Password Validation Without using regex

Tags: javascript

I want to validate password field which will have atleast 1 character ,atleast  1 small letter,atleast 1 big letter , atleast 1 number and the length should be more than 8.

How can i do this without using regex method?

Comment: With code. Where is it?

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: same, how regex do it, scan and check

Comment: For what need you a code? I think it will be: `function valpass(s){/*todo: copy check from SO answer*/return true;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var password = 'Password8';
var hasBigLetter   = false;
var hasSmallLetter = false;
var hasNumber      = false;
for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
  var charCode = password.charCodeAt(i);
  if(charCode > 47 && charCode < 58)
    hasNumber = true;
  if(charCode > 64 && charCode < 91)
    hasBigLetter = true;
  if(charCode > 96 && charCode < 123)
    hasSmallLetter = true;
}
if(hasBigLetter && hasSmallLetter && hasNumber)
  alert("password ok");
else
  alert("password is missing "+(hasBigLetter)?(hasSmallLetter)?(hasNumber === false)?"number":"something else":"small letter":"big letter");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the code:

```
function check(s){
 var c,C,d; //bool vars, indicates, that we have (c - lowchar, C - upchar, d - digit)
 if (s.length<8) return false;
 for(var i=0,n=s.length;i<n;i++){
   var ch = s.charAt(i);
   if(ischar(ch)) c = 1;
   if(isChar(ch)) C = 1;
   if(isdigit(ch))d = 1;
   if(c&&C&&d) return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

You should implement only ischar/isChar and isdigit functions):

> bool ischar(ch): checks, that ch is lowercase letter
>   bool isChar(ch):checks, that ch is uppercase letter
>   bool isdigit(ch): checks, that ch is digit

Comment: Could you expand the names of the variables to make what you are trying to show more clear?

Comment: I add some description for this :)

Comment: Note that in JS, you can just use `c = true;` instead of `c = 1`. The first is a real boolean value, the second is actually assigning a number to the variable.

Comment: `c = 1` shorter and works.. is this realy mean in the `password validation`?